# Unit Testing Apigee APIs

Tags: apigee

I've looked through the documentation and don't see anything related to unit testing of APIs created with Apigee.  With our current homegrown APIs we're writing today, we can inject and mock dependencies for unit testing and integration testing. Is this something that's possible with Apigee at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apigee policies are more properly understood to be configuration items and as such would not be unit testable - rather they are only testable as an integration target which are readily automated with our Maven plugin.

Java callouts, javascript callouts, Node servers, python callouts and the like are testable in an offline mode using the same tools you use today. Your harnesses of course will have to take into account the context of execution - which is not trivial. Apigee today does not provide any tooling to provide that context. Of course if you already unit testing homegrown APIs you probably have experience with something like RhinoUnit.

To summarize - my point of view is that policies are configuration and as such are not unit test targets. Some resources (which are referenced in a call out policy for instance) are code and are appropriate targets for unit test.

Comment: Completely agree on policies and that integration test targets are the appropriate place to exercise those.  My question is more specifically geared toward custom Node.js code you may write as part of an API proxy. Understand that Node servers can be tested outside of Apigee, etc. I'm was hoping there was some way we could validate (via something like Jasmine) any custom code added to an API proxy.

Comment: As of today I unit test node apps (I tend to think of them as apps just to force myself to recognize they run differently than proxies or other callouts) offline using my typical stand alone test harnesses and utilities ([node-unit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) or [expresso](http://visionmedia.github.io/expresso/) for instance).

Comment: cool makes sense, so it's really a process issue then for teams developing things with Apigee, to just be smart about what makes its way into proxies. Has there been any talk of linking proxies to version control systems? Meaning I do something like `git push origin head` and it's reflected in the associated proxy?

Comment: I can just say "stay tuned".

Answer (score 0):

While Apigee doesn't support a unit testing framework directly in our products, there are plenty of external options out there you can use for mass testing.  For example, there's [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and [frisbyjs](http://frisbyjs.com/).

Comment: so that would be integration testing.  There is no direct support for unit testing.  Is there any plan to add this? I worry about a loss of test coverage when moving any orchestration into Apigee.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why JMeter and frisbyjs couldn't be used for unit testing, too.  Separately, you can use the Apigee API Console, trace tool, and SmartDocs for testing single API calls, but they aren't specifically built for that functionality.  Those 3 tools will certainly help, so I have never had concern about loss of test coverage.  Please feel free to talk to us and we can address any specific concerns you have on unit testing.

Comment: those are integration test tools.. not unit tests.  You're not testing individual units.  In unit test frameworks there is traditionally the ability to mock dependencies and verify domain logic is being executed correctly given a set of expected values. Specifically if we write custom node code inside an endpoint, or make multiple calls and create a response composed of multiple calls.  Basically any place where we could introduce what amounts to application logic is my concern.

Comment: Our trace tool will help you with seeing values at runtime based on mock dependencies.  Please feel free to contact us-- we'll be happy to ensure all levels of testing are not a concern.

Comment: For unit testing, you might want to mock the backend and try out the flow. This will test the proxy flow. Mocking the backend has several HTTP stubbing option which you can find.

Comment: Thanks Srikanth. Once those are setup, is there anyway to execute those from any type of continuous integration server like Jenkins/Team City? My main concern is making sure that everything we decide to do via Apigee has a way to be tested via mocks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Unit testing You can create Mock API proxy on APIGEE which stores dummy responses. Use this mock API as your target and using postman you can test request/response.

Answer (score -1):

Apigee api can be tested using postman and you should enable trace in debug -->start trace and once you fire the api you can see the logs/values/policy execution in detail in trace and this way we can do unit testing.